# creating a service using code from svcutil

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, .net-4.0

I do not really understand what has been output from svcutil, can someone explain?

in vs command prompt i used: svcitil /mc *.wsdl *.xsd /language:c#

```
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "3.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName="GenericInboundBrokerSoap")]
public interface GenericInboundBrokerSoap
{

    // CODEGEN: Generating message contract since element name SourceID from namespace http://tempuri.org/ is not marked nillable
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/BrokerInboundRequest", ReplyAction="*")]
    BrokerInboundRequestResponse BrokerInboundRequest(BrokerInboundRequestRequest request);
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "3.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(IsWrapped=false)]
public partial class BrokerInboundRequestRequest
{

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Name="BrokerInboundRequest", Namespace="http://tempuri.org/", Order=0)]
    public BrokerInboundRequestRequestBody Body;

    public BrokerInboundRequestRequest()
    {
    }

    public BrokerInboundRequestRequest(BrokerInboundRequestRequestBody Body)
    {
        this.Body = Body;
    }
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "3.0.0.0")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Namespace="http://tempuri.org/")]
public partial class BrokerInboundRequestRequestBody
{

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(EmitDefaultValue=false, Order=0)]
    public string SourceID;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(EmitDefaultValue=false, Order=1)]
    public string TokenID;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(EmitDefaultValue=false, Order=2)]
    public string xml;

    public BrokerInboundRequestRequestBody()
    {
    }

    public BrokerInboundRequestRequestBody(string SourceID, string TokenID, string xml)
    {
        this.SourceID = SourceID;
        this.TokenID = TokenID;
        this.xml = xml;
    }
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "3.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(IsWrapped=false)]
public partial class BrokerInboundRequestResponse
{

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Name="BrokerInboundRequestResponse", Namespace="http://tempuri.org/", Order=0)]
    public BrokerInboundRequestResponseBody Body;

    public BrokerInboundRequestResponse()
    {
    }

    public BrokerInboundRequestResponse(BrokerInboundRequestResponseBody Body)
    {
        this.Body = Body;
    }
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "3.0.0.0")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Namespace="http://tempuri.org/")]
public partial class BrokerInboundRequestResponseBody
{

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(EmitDefaultValue=false, Order=0)]
    public string BrokerInboundRequestResult;

    public BrokerInboundRequestResponseBody()
    {
    }

    public BrokerInboundRequestResponseBody(string BrokerInboundRequestResult)
    {
        this.BrokerInboundRequestResult = BrokerInboundRequestResult;
    }
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "3.0.0.0")]
public interface GenericInboundBrokerSoapChannel : GenericInboundBrokerSoap, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel
{
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "3.0.0.0")]
public partial class GenericInboundBrokerSoapClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<GenericInboundBrokerSoap>, GenericInboundBrokerSoap
{

    public GenericInboundBrokerSoapClient()
    {
    }

    public GenericInboundBrokerSoapClient(string endpointConfigurationName) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName)
    {
    }

    public GenericInboundBrokerSoapClient(string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress)
    {
    }

    public GenericInboundBrokerSoapClient(string endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress)
    {
    }

    public GenericInboundBrokerSoapClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(binding, remoteAddress)
    {
    }

    [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    BrokerInboundRequestResponse GenericInboundBrokerSoap.BrokerInboundRequest(BrokerInboundRequestRequest request)
    {
        return base.Channel.BrokerInboundRequest(request);
    }

    public string BrokerInboundRequest(string SourceID, string TokenID, string xml)
    {
        BrokerInboundRequestRequest inValue = new BrokerInboundRequestRequest();
        inValue.Body = new BrokerInboundRequestRequestBody();
        inValue.Body.SourceID = SourceID;
        inValue.Body.TokenID = TokenID;
        inValue.Body.xml = xml;

        //do the hokey pokey here?

        BrokerInboundRequestResponse retVal = ((GenericInboundBrokerSoap)(this)).BrokerInboundRequest(inValue);
        return retVal.Body.BrokerInboundRequestResult;
    }
}
```

How/what way can I create a WCF service? I have created a service using:

[image]

What do I implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to distinguish two things:

- the service (server side), your wcf service
- the proxy to call your service (client side) create by svcutil (used
  by VS with "Add a service reference command")

if you have created your proxy code using svcutil it means that you already know the address of a wsdl contract file, it means that a service exists already.

You can take a look at these links to find some examples:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42643/Creating-and-Consuming-Your-First-WCF-Service
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmeier/archive/2007/10/15/how-to-create-a-hello-world-wcf-service-using-visual-studio.aspx

Comment: A 3rd party is sending me some data, they also gave me the wsdl file, I generated the proxy code using that wsdl file. Does that mean I need to create a server side service?

Comment: no! if you just want to consume an existing service (client side) you only need to generate your proxy: 1/ as you have already done with svcutil or 2/ with VS "Add a service reference" command. And you can easily use it `var service = new GenericInboundBrokerSoapClient();` and calling your service methods `service.AnyMethod...` and disposing/closing your service channel (within an `using` statement for example)

Comment: I presumed I need to create a server side service - because I will be sent data from the 3rd party?

Comment: Maybe "sending" is the wrong term for you to be using. You are "calling" the 3rd party service and "receiving" some data.

Comment: ok... so if I am receiving data from a 3rd party service that means I do need to create a WCF service right? Sorry I am confused by all this, I am used to REST services.

Comment: @Haroon, You will need to decide if you want to host the service and have the 3rd party call it, or visa versa.  I suppose the main difference is that typically the client side would decide when the service is called.  Do you need this data on request or are you happy to wait for them to give it to you when they see fit?

Comment: @BuhBuh Wait for them to give it to me

Comment: @Haroon, ok so that sounds like you do want to build a service.  Although if they have given you a wsdl then that probably means that they have built the service already, but not necessarily. They might have just written the wsdl as a definition for you to work with.

Comment: @BuhBuh They have built their end (I think) but they have given me the wsdl to work with as a guideline on how we will *receive* data from them. We kinda have to do it their way or the highway unfortunately. Our clients giving us work.

Comment: @Haroon, ok, that's fine.  You really need to know what they have built on their end.  Did they give you a URL ending in `service.svc`?  That would indicated they have a service already.  

Data can be sent in a request or a response, so you really need to find out if they expect you to be the server side or the client side.

Comment: @BuhBuh No they never - just a wsdl file and a few xsd files. As far as I know we are expected to be the Server Side, I will confirm though.

Comment: A wsdl is "just" a contract that tells essentialy what functionalities can be offered by the service and where you can find it (endpoints). It does not tell you how the service is implemented (technology, availability...) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language

Comment: A service cannot send you something unless you ask for it (call the service), so in your case everything shows that there is a service available (somewhere) and they (the person that hosts the service) gave the informations to call this service (wsdl). So once you have built your proxy (with svcutil) you will call the service and eventually send some data (parameters), as you do with REST services.

Answer (score 0):

You don't change or implement stuff, you just use the generated proxy.

```
using (var thing = new GenericInboundBrokerSoapClient()) {
  thing.CallToMethodExposedByService();
}
```

You will get a value of the return type proper or a request-related return type value depending on whether you use synchronous or asynchronous methods; in some cases only the asynchronous methods are available (*à la* Silverlight).